# Difference in how the page fault handler handles read vs write access requests?

Tags: memory, operating-system, page-fault

All the research I've done indicates only that a memory access has occurred, not if it was a read or a write access. Does that mean it doesn't matter? What if the page replacement algorithm which handles page faults depending on when they were last referenced? Would a read cause the reference bit to be set to 0? I assume it's still moved to the tail of the array since it was most recently used.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking what the hardware reports to the software page fault handler, or what the software should do with that information?  What does "the reference bit" mean to you?

Comment: The reference bit I'm referring is in relation to the clock page replacement algorithm. To my knowledge, each page is given a bit to represent if they have been used since last the OS attempted to replace it. If it's one, the algorithm skips and moves to the next least recently used page until it finds a page with a 0 bit, which it removes then replaces it with the access request. My question is in this scenario, would a read access also write it's request? Hopefully that clarifies things.